# C stdlib fopen cannot find files when passing file name as a variable

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

Im reading user input and get the correct string, but when I try to pass the same string to fopen it cant find the file.

When I hard code the file name as a string into the function call it works, but then I also get some kind of error using any of the file writing functions.

Feels like nothing works to be honest. I have tried the full file path, moving the file to run directory and reopening visual studio. Both problems persist.

Can I somehow make sure my stdlib isnt corrupted or something?

EDIT:
The filename is now parsed correctly thanks to your help!

I still have the following problem though:

```
struct time {
    char* desc;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
};

void saveToFile(unsigned int count, struct time** reservations) {
    char* file = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char* clean = calloc(strlen(file), sizeof(char));
    if (clean != NULL) {
        strncpy(clean, file, strlen(file) - 1);
        FILE* writeTo = fopen(clean, "w");
        if (writeTo != NULL) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                char s[80] = { 0 };
                sprintf(s, "A %s %d %d %d\n", reservations[i]->desc, reservations[i]->month,
                    reservations[i]->day, reservations[i]->hour);
                printf("%s", s);
                fprintf(writeTo, "A %s %d %d %d", reservations[i]->desc, reservations[i]->month,
                    reservations[i]->day, reservations[i]->hour);
            }
            if (ferror) printf("An error occurred while saving the data...\n");
            else printf("The calendar has successfully been saved to \"%s\"\n", clean);
            fclose(writeTo);
        }
        else printf("Could not find file...");
    }
}
```

Running this code writes seemingly correctly to the file now, but sets the ferror flag and I get the print accordingly. ERRNO is 0. How could I go about finding the cause of this?

Comment: You'd better paste your code that is failing.

Comment: Cant right now.

Comment: Well, this question probably won't get an answer until you do - and people may downvote in the meantime, so you may want to delete it for now and undelete after you put in the code.  Also include the input you use, and an exact description of the errors you get.

Comment: I'll tell you right now, though, that it won't be a corrupted stdlib.  [select isn't broken](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: How do you read the 'correct string'?  Is it with `fgets()`?  Do you remember to remove the line endings (CRLF, though you should only see a newline, aka LF)?  How do you demonstrate that you've got the right string?  I recommend something like `printf("filename: [[%s]]\n", filename);` (where you can use different characters in place of the brackets if you prefer).  The known characters before and after the file name are important; they're very helpful for spotting problems like CR still in the file name.

Comment: The other primary possibility is that your program isn't running with the same current working directory as you expect.  Absolute path names should work reliably — that's why they're important — but relative names only work if the process's current directory is where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unlikely that your stdlib is corrupt, you will have to show us your code so that we can find the error.

Maybe you have a \n at the end of your input.